# Pin number authentication

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication, bcrypt

How secure is it to use a pin number instead of a password for authentication? I'm designing a small CRM in Laravel 5.5 and I haven't used any modern methods as of yet to create a secure login system. However I would much prefer users to be able to log in with a pin than a password as it is also easier on iOS and Android apps and it's one of the reasons Barclays is one of my favourite apps. It would be a massive help if someone could shed some light and point me in the right direction. Thank you :-)

Comment: There are only 10000 possible 4-digit PINs.  Make of that what you will...

Comment: I should have said 5-digit pin as that is what the Barclays app uses. How come banks can securely use these pins as log ins to their apps?

Comment: It's unclear that this is a particularly secure approach, even when banks do it.

Comment: True, however there is far less access to mobile apps installed on a device that has a previously-authenticated session than having a pin on the web. I wouldn't recommend PIN on the web unless user remembers session and pin is solely a client-side mechanism to validate and use session... but even then, questionable security IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: a previous session should exist before a pin entry should be considered.

A pin should only be usable once a user has authenticated. In the case of a native app, the device in which the app is used is typically only used by one (or very few) people. Initial login requires the username and password. Pins are basically a gatekeeper to an existing session.

Once authenticated, users can assign a pin to their session (stored on device). Pin entry should only allow so many invalid attempts instead of unlimited attempts. This prevents the ability to brute force or sequential attack/abuse the pin entry. If the pin entry fails after X attempts, you clear the session and related data, then prompt for the username/password again.

As with passwords, do not store pins in plaintext. Hash them with randomized salts, just as you do using the `Hash` façade in Laravel.

(please add to this if I'm missing anything!)

Comment: How about a pin for limited access. A mobile app would have limited functionality compared to a web app, is this considered secure enough?

Comment: Depends, I suppose... I'd still authenticate the user before allowing pin use.

Answer (score 0):

Well i suppose it is relatively secure, of course it is less secure than an actual password because of the amount of possible combinations. So it would be relatively easier to find out the pin. Down below is a comparison of the amount of combinations.

If you have a pin that consists out of 4 numbers, then there are 10000 possible combinations. Most passwords these days are at least 8 characters long i think? I don't know how many possible different characters can be used, but if its 72(uppercase & lowercase & numbers & shift combinations of 0 - 9) then that would already lead to 72^8 possible combinations, which is about 7,2*10^14 combinations. So of course a password is a lot more secure.

But i have some ideas which might give you some ideas, you could set a maximum amount of tries like most phones have these days. So for example if the maximum amount of tries is 4, and you put in the wrong pin 4 times then it will lock and requires something like email authentication to unlock again.

You could also say that you don't want to limit it to just numbers, and also add upper and lowercase characters. If the pin is 4 characters long then there would be 62^4 (26(alphabet) + 26 + 10 = 62) possible combinations, which is about 14.8 million combinations. Which is quite a lot.

I hope this helps you a bit, and good luck :D

(by the way i couldn't add a comment because i don't have enough points)